# Phantomjs jquery dialog popup

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I can handle it with FF web driver (selenium python) but when I change phantomjs the driver .it didnt handle it. is it possible to handle it?
the program must work on server so what must I do?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, this is not currently possible. The PhantomJS ghostdriver does not implement the primitives for handling alerts/prompts. See https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/20

This is also unlikely to change since [development of PhantomJS has been discontinued](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344).

> the program must work on server so what must I do?

Your best option is to use the headless versions of Chrome or Firefox, which can run in a headless environment like PhantomJS just fine. Both Chrome (chromedriver) and Firefox (geckodriver) implement the necessary primitives for handling alerts/prompts.

Another option is that you can use a virtual screen program (e.g. xvfb) to enable you to use a headed browser in a headless environment.